# Set hostname aliases for OpenSSH on windows

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

My google Fu seems to have failed me here. I know how to create host aliases on unix by adding them to ~/.ssh/config. However I can't seem to find an equivalent on windows. How do I create hostname aliases for SSH on windows? So that I can use `ssh foo` instead of the whole `user@ip`.

Windows version: 10 
Build: 18362

Comment: add to question: What version of windows. Add os tag. Remove powershell tag.